# Wireless not working on Dell Latiude 3330 ubuntu preinstalled

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom

I just bought a Dell Latitude 3330 with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed. Wireless worked without a problem for a few days and then stopped. The wireless broadcom is BCM4352. Tried everything but still not working. Works with wire and Reliance datacard. Please help resolve this issue. Thanks. 
Suparna

Comment: Please edit you question to add details of the wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: I have the same problem with dell M4800 ubuntu preinstalled. Worked when I set up ubuntu the first time. Back then I struggled with the graphics. Now I have set up ubuntu from installation and the graphics work. But the wireless bcm 4352 has no driver... Additional Drivers offers the STA driver - this doesnt work!

Answer (score 0):

You should install the wifi driver from the additional drivers tab from the settings menu,where you can find your required driver for your wireless card.